# Alert is not displayed....When clicking on push notifications

Tags: react-native, react-native-push-notification

I am running sample application..... I am using [this](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) module for push notifications..... My problem is when clicking on push notifications after clearing the instance of the app...In onNotification() console is printed but the alert is not displayed.... even try to keep time out for the alert but it doesn't work..... this is a problem is getting for the only iOS....... Please give any suggestions.......

```
onNotification: notification => {
    console.log('NOTIFICATION:', notification)
        if(notification.notificationType === XXX){
         alert('NOTIFICATION:'+JSON.stringify(notification))
         }
   }
```

Comment: May be you forgot to add `notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);` in the end of `onNotification`. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html#finish

Comment: Hi, @TuấnTrầnDuy notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData); it's not working for me.......

Comment: I fixed it by adding a SetTimeout of 1000ms to the alert. Maybe the app isn't ready as fast as the alert...